# Test IF dynamic range refers to a specific range

Tags: vba, excel

I am running a macro which defines a dynamic range. What I am struggling with is incorporating an IF statement that tests if the dynamic range refers to a specific range. I am trying with the below but get 'Run-type error '13': Type-mismatch'. Can someone tell me what's wrong with this?

```
Sub TestTwo()

Dim colRange    As Long
Dim rowRange    As Long
Dim rngMain     As Range

rowRange = 10

   With Worksheets(1)
    colRange = .Cells(10, 12).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rngMain = .Range(.Cells(rowRange + 200, colRange + 1), .Cells(217, 12))
    Range("L210:L217").FormulaR1C1 = "=+R[-60]C-R[-60]C[-1]"
    If Not rngMain = Range("L210:L217") Then Range("L210:L217").AutoFill Destination:=rngMain, Type:=xlFillDefault
   End With
End Sub
```

The reason I want to test what "rngMain" refers to is that in case rngMain refers to L210:L217 then I get 'Run-time error 1004': Application defined or defined object error' otherwise the code runs as it should.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Perhaps `If Not rngMain.address = "$L$210:$L$217"`. Otherwise you are trying to compare values (which won't work anyway as you have found).

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Do you know the reason why I get 'Run-time error 1004': Application defined or defined object error' when rngMain refers to L210:L217 in the first place?

Comment: @SJR You beat me to it. +1

Comment: Not sure but probably because you cannot compare multiple cells in that way. To compare values you have to loop through each cell.

Comment: What's the purpose of the dynamic range?  And what's in L210:L217 that's causing the error?  On which line(s) do you get each of those errors?

Comment: I'm gonna take a shot in the dark here: is it a gigantic worksheet of manually entered values and lots of formulas, parts of which sometimes get accidentally or inadvertently overwritten?

Comment: The macro populates a range with a formula. The range it needs to insert a formula into is dependent on how many columns are filled in by the users. There is nothing in L210:L217 before the macro is run.

Comment: @ashleedawg not exactly but the issue is similar I think

Comment: Yeah I get the impression that you're trying to "put out fires", as in, avoid issues  & errors caused by another macro, by changing others to just work around it (probably pretty common when we're first learning to code, I was there once!)  If you don't know why it's causing that error there, then that  also implies that you don't fully understand what this one's doing either... but that can be a good thing -- it's not a lot of code, it's not too late to start fresh.  There are many different ways to do most anything in Excel and/or VBA.

Comment: ...Your call, of course but if you were to back up a step and explain more about where and when these formulas need to be filled in like this (and why they can't be there before the manual entry) there's likely a better way to handle this.  A screen shot of what's going on ([edit]ed onto your question) would be helpful too.

Comment: thanks @ashleedawg. You are right I am just trying my wings with vba. I have managed to get this to work, and whilst it might not be the prettiest solution, I'll leave it as is as I have got limited time and need to move on to the next issue that needs to be resolved.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are comparing references there instead of values, you can try:

```
If Not rngMain.Address = "$L$210:$L$217" Then Range("L210:L217").AutoFill Destination:=rngMain, Type:=xlFillDefault
```

But what if they only select a single cell inside that range or if their selection includes part of that range? If you want to, you can also check if their selection intersects with `L210:L217`:

```
If Intersect(rngMain,Range("L210:L217")) Is Nothing Then Range("L210:L217").AutoFill Destination:=rngMain, Type:=xlFillDefault
```